# No Hilbert space can have countable Hamel basis without using Baire's Category theorem

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

I want to prove that no Hilbert space can have countable Hamel basis just using the fact that any finite dimensional subspace is closed (more specifically without using Baire's theorem). I saw a paper by NAM-KIu TSING solving the same problem for Banach space. But, the proof is not much intuitive. Is it possible to give a easier proof for Hilbert space ?

Using proof by contradiction, the aim is to somehow find a Cauchy sequence and then use completeness to get a limit and show that cauchy sequence does not converge to that limit.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean when you say "I have to prove..."? Why are you not allowed to use the Baire category theorem?

Comment: @YemonChoi: I think it is pretty straightforward what I mean here. I want to know an alternate proof.

Comment: The language "I have to prove" means, to me, a _need_ or a _demand_. This makes it sound like an assigned task. Most BC arguments can be converted to sliding hump arguments, anyway

Comment: What Yemon is saying in his previous comment is that this sounds like a homework assignment. If that is the case, then please be aware that we don't discuss HW at this site.

Answer (score 4):

Nam-Kiu Tsing argument indeed become way much simpler for Hilbert spaces. In fact I wouldn't be surprise if his argument was inspired from the (very easy) case of Hilbert spaces:

If you have a countable Hamel basis you can turn it into a countable orthonormal Hamel basis $(e_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ by Gram-Schmidt process. Then $\sum 2^{-n}e_n$ will be an element of your Hilbert space by completeness but it is not going to be equal to any finite linear combination of the $e_n$ by simply computing the distant between $x$ and such a combination.